# Beginner c# class/constructor/if statement question

Tags: c#

Wrote some program to if students are eligible to be honor students based on their gpa, got no problem with that but I want to add department based honor system.
I mean; students in engineering department need 3 gpa to be honor student but arc students need 3.5 gpa to be honor students.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Lifetime;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Denemee
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student student1 = new Student("Oguz" , "Engineering" , 4);
            Student student2 = new Student("i2", "Arc", 2);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class Student
        {
            public string name;
            public string dept;
            public int gpa;

            public Student(string name, string dept, int gpa)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.dept = dept;
                this.gpa = gpa;

                if (IsHonor() == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name + " is honor student");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name + " is not honor student");
                }
            }

            public bool IsHonor()
            {
                if (gpa >= 3)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is?

Comment: `gpa` is an `int`, so it makes no sense to compare it to `3.5`. It should be a `decimal`, `float` or `double`.

Comment: As there is no question, here is some question that my lead to something better.
You want honor to be based on Dept, but I don't see the 3/2.5 in the code.
Perhaps you want to store it there in a class, dictionnary? Maybe you can hard code it with if/switch case? You already access Gpa in the `isHonor`, maybe you can test the dept there too.
Should a construtor write to console tho ? Should the comming into existence of a student scream to the world "Honor!"?
Or is it something that comes later in his life. Should the honor system be build directly in the matrice that birth student?

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to solve this would be to make department an actual class:

```
public class Department{
    public decimal MinGpa {get;Set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then you associate each student with an actual department object:

```
public class Student{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Department Dept {get;set;}
    public decimal Gpa {get;set;}
    public bool IsHonorStudent() => Gpa > Dept.MinGpa;
}
```

The nice thing with this approach is that it maps very well to a database model, all students goes into one table, and departments into another, and you can make queries asking for all honor-students.

You could further extend the model by adding courses and the number of points to separate tables, so the Gpa is calculated on demand.